# With Outlook 2016 : MAPISendMail fails in an windows application and returning "MAPI_E_FAILURE" as error code

Tags: c++, mfc, outlook-2016

I am trying to send an email using a c++application where I loaded MAPI32.dll first and then tried accessing the MAPISendMail with the necessary parameters being passed. When I tried to execute this step it throwing an exception "Access violation..". When I click continue then it throws "MAPI_E_FAILURE" as the error  code. But the same piece of code works fine for windows 7 and outlook 2013 environment.

The environment I am using is windows 10 and outlook 2016 and issue exists in this OS with outlook 2016.

I have taken this link as reference:[MAPISendMail_Expert](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/1820/Sending-Email-with-MAPI.html)

I could not trace out what exactly is the issue. It would be greatly appreciable if any one could help me.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what is causing issue, it is because the c++ application I have launched is running with `admin privileges` and the outlook that is running in the background is launched with `non-admin` privileges.

Then I launched my outlook in admin mode("Run as administrator"), and sent an email from my c++ application and did it successfully.

To brief, both the application should be launched at same privileges i.e. either running both the applications as `non-admin` or running both of them (C++ app & outlook) as `administrator`.

Answer (score -1):

I also met this issue, after testing , i found that you should set

`_T("SMTP:") + recipient.m_strAddress`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd296720(v=vs.85).aspx , pay attention to `lpszAddress,`
the format are `FAX:206-555-1212` and `SMTP:M@X.COM` , I have solved this issue by this way.

Comment: please also notice this :https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/63e9f5b2-f5f2-4cf8-bdc2-ca1fad88ebe5/problem-with-outlook-and-mapisendmail-returns-mapiefailure-when-outlook-is-running?forum=outlookdev